# Command not found error when i use shell command in a function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am pretty new to shell script. I want to make a simple script that will install my script to the system. So I have tried to the write a simple script for that. Here is my code below.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
#Purpose: It is the install script for Template.sh
#Version:1.0
#Created Date: Thu Mar 16 04:10:20 PM IST 2023
#Modified Date:
#Author: Sayantan Sinharay
# START #

installPackage() {
  local PATH=$1
  if [[ -f PATH/template ]]; then
    cat template.sh >template
  else
    touch template
    cat template.sh >template
    chmod 777 template
    sudo mv template PATH
  fi
}
INSTALL_PATH="/bin/"

if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
  INSTALL_PATH=$1
elif [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: Expected 1 argument. Got $#"
  exit 1
fi

installPackage INSTALL_PATH
# touch hello.sh --> These are working
# chmod +x hello.sh --> These are working
# END #
```

On running this I am getting an `command not found` error

Here is the error in the terminal

```
./installTemplate.sh: line 15: touch: command not found
./installTemplate.sh: line 16: cat: command not found
./installTemplate.sh: line 17: chmod: command not found
./installTemplate.sh: line 18: sudo: command not found
```

Comment: You're overriding `PATH` with whatever `$1` is, is that intentional?

Comment: Assuming you didn't mean to override `PATH`, which is a system variable that configures where to search for executables, it's recommended to never use ALL_CAPS in your own variables because they might conflict with pre-existing system variables like in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I got the issue. As `PATH` is a reserved variable in shell. Hence the commands were not working. But I have made that variable `local` then why it is giving this issue.

Comment: Making it `local` localizes the change to that single function, but it still applies within that function so it is dictating how your script looks for things like `touch` or `cat` that you call during the function. If it can't find those commands in any of the locations on your custom PATH then it prints an error.

Comment: This is why you should use lowercase, f/e `path`, for your own variables

Comment: Using lower-case variable names is actually POSIX-standardized convention: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html specifies all-caps names for use by the shell and other POSIX-defined tools, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are explicitly reserved for application use. That's your script -- it's an application. Read that spec keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`installPackage INSTALL_PATH` is likely a typo - you meant `installPackage "$INSTALL_PATH"`.

The former passes the literal string `INSTALL_PATH` while the latter passes the contents of the variable.